# Parsing through PHP, echo not working

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse some html with a php document that I upload to my web host. When I try this (with the last echo in there just to see if it works):

```
<?php
//a URL you want to retrieve
$my_url = 'http://pointstreak.com/prostats/standings.html?leagueid=49&seasonid=12983';
$html = file_get_contents($my_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//Put your XPath Query here
$my_xpath_query = "//div[@id='statscontainer']/table/tr/td/table[@class='tablelines']/tr/td";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

// Create an array to hold the content of the nodes
$standingsArray = array();

//here we loop through our results (a DOMDocument Object)
foreach ($result_rows as $result_object){
    $standingsArray[] = $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

// Remove the first 12 observations from $standingsArray (table headers)
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    unset($standingsArray[0]);
    $standingsArray = array_values($results_rows);
}

// Remove the 12 observations at index 96 (table headers)
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    unset($standingsArray[96]);
    $standingsArray = array_values($results_rows);
}

foreach ($standingsArray as $arrayValue) {
    echo $arrayValue;
}

echo “HEYHEY”;

?>
```

The output on my webpage is: 
    â€œHEYHEYâ€

However, if I change the line

```
foreach ($standingsArray as $arrayValue) {
        echo $arrayValue;
    }
```

to:

```
foreach ($standingsArray as $arrayValue) {
        echo "$arrayValue";
    }
```

then even the 
"â€œHEYHEYâ€" 
goes away and all I have is a blank webpage.

Comment: http://ideone.com/YB8vZY

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` like @Jite said to do.

Comment: This is not a php error. You have a character set mismatch. e.g. dumping utf-8 text into an iso-8859 display environment.

Comment: It looks like your quotes around HEYHEY are kinda funky. I think you have a left double quotation mark instead of a regular quotation mark. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735921/are-there-different-types-of-double-quotes-in-utf-8-php-str-replace. Also, I think the document you are trying to upload is empty, or it's not getting it.

Comment: How can I fix my character set mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ($standingsArray as $arrayValue) 
{
    echo utf8_encode($arrayValue);
}
```

UPDATE:

"HEYHEY" seems to be a different font, try removing/replacing it with normal text.

Comment: No luck. Thanks though.

Comment: The last echo was not an ordinary text, I opened in notepad++ and deleted the echo and typed again, it's running correctly.

Comment: Oh my god you're right. How did you discover that? Does notepad++ warn you of things like that? I would have never been able to do that myself. Wow, thanks. Now I just need to resolve all these warnings and issues.

Comment: No warning, nothing, Just tried with different values, then I got to know.

Comment: Wow. What a strange bug. Well thank you tons. I wish I could upvote your comment but I don't have enough reputation.