# Dockerfile error: /bin/sh: 1: [“python”,: not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

here is my Dockerfile tried to build:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# install flask server
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY app.py /
RUN pip install flask

# install ruby
RUN \
  apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev ruby-bundler && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install lua
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y luajit luarocks

# Define default command.
CMD [“python”, “app.py”]
```

However, it shown up with error
    /bin/sh: 1: [“python”,: not found

I have no idea why this happened. Could someone please help me with it?

Comment: I don't know docker, but it looks like you have fancy quotes in there rather than normal double quotes ...

Comment: I see curly quotes. What are you using to write this file? Use a text editor.

Comment: You should disable your Chinese input method when you writing code :)

Comment: **Not** [python].

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to use the right [`CMD` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) with `""`, not `“”`:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
```

Comment: So many evil double quotes out there -- http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%22&r=None (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18739948/4148708)

Comment: @evilSnobu it reminds me of the evil hyphen vs. minus: http://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309