# invalid character error on eclipse docker using xming on windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, docker, x11, xming

[Inavlid Character error in eclipse on docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXZhD.png)

I have created a container using file similar to 
https://github.com/batmat/docker-eclipse/blob/master/Dockerfile
on docker installed on windows 7.I did need to make a change of setting the locale first in dockerfile. I tried with both en_US.UTF8 and en_IN.UTF8.

When I start the container I am successfully able to open the eclipse in xming but eclipse is giving invalid character error on double quotes.(Probably on some other characters)

Is there any other change/setting I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a file encoding problem (because the syntax error is not displayed at the first character), but that **instead of ASCII quotation marks (`"`) [similar looking characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739948/6505250)** (e. g. `＂`, `ײ`, `״`, `ʺ`, [etc.](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%22&r=None)) were used.

Replace line 17 with the following line:

```
System.out.println("Hello There");
```

See also: [Java Language Specification - 3.10.5. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Comment: Right! That is a part of my question. Normally I am using eclipse on windows and don't have any such issues.However When I type the double quotes in eclipse on docker using xming    it gets replaced with this character. I had encoding error coming initially and after adding UTF locale to dockerfile, the error didn't come but my typed character (double quotes) is not proper.Any suggestions?

Comment: Does copying and pasting work? I don't think the wrong autocorrect of quotes happens in Eclipse. Which quotation marks do you get in other editors via Xming?

Comment: Yes  that should work. The problem  is the characters entered from keyboard into eclipse is not correct. As you mentioned It enters similar looking character rather than double quotes.

Comment: Is this just the case with Eclipse or also with other editors and in the terminal via Xming?